# Mount bind not taking affect in fstab - Centos 6

Tags: centos, mount, fstab

I am using this line in fstab to bind /sftp/feeds/incoming to /var/www/online/public_html/feeds

```
/sftp/feeds/incoming   /var/www/online/public_html/feeds   none   bind   0 0
```

But it is not taking affect.

If I use:

```
mount --bind /var/www/online/public_html/feeds /sftp/feeds/incoming
```

On the command line that does the job fine but of course is lost on reboot.

Comment: What does happen? Also, does `mount /var/www/online/public_html/feeds` say anything that suggests what may be up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the syntax is wrong or supplied parameters are in wrong order. It should be same as your `mount` command:

```
/var/www/online/public_html/feeds  /sftp/feeds/incoming     none   bind   0 0
```

From [mount man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount):

> The bind mounts.
>
> Since Linux 2.4.0 it is possible to remount part of the file hierarchy
>   somewhere else. The call is
>
> ```
> mount --bind olddir newdir
> ```
>
> or shortoption
>
> ```
> mount -B olddir newdir
> ```
>
> or fstab entry is:
>
> ```
> /olddir /newdir none bind
> ```
>
> After this call the same contents is accessible in two places. One can also remount a single file (on a single file).
>
> This call attaches only (part of) a single filesystem, not possible submounts. The entire file hierarchy including submounts is
>   attached a second place using